# Relation between dualizing complex and cotangent complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I'd like to know when is it possible (and makes sense) to find a relation between the cotangent and the dualizing complex in the setting of algebraic geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For varities that are local complete intersections (inside the projective space) , the cotangent complex is a perfect complex and hence there is a good notion of determinant. In this case it follows that determinant of the cotangent complex is the dualizing sheaf. This more or less follows by definition and Hartshorne Chapter 3, Theorem 7.11. I am not sure what happens outside this relatively easy case.

Comment: +1, this is a good start. One minor nitpick: whether a variety is a local complete intersection or not is an intrinsic property which does not depend on the embedding, so you do not need to add the parenthetical about inside projective space.